# regex match if dash is within string for n times

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a string if it contains a dash for more than 3 times:

```
string-has-4-dashes-example
```

The regex would not match on this example:

```
string-has-3-dashes
```

This unfortunately does not work

```
.*-{3,}.*
```

My goal is to build a regex like this:

```
\/germany\/.*-(\d{3,}\.html|\/product\/view\/id.*)$
```

Which will match URLs of a similar type like this

```
https://www.test.de/germany/bla-blub-test-example-new-2-189.html
```

But not:

```
https://www.test.de/germany/test-this-1931.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match a string with 3+ hyphens:

```
^(?:[^-]*-){4}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gdITws/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[^-]*-`: Match 0+ non-hyphen characters followed by a hyphen
- `)`: End non-capture group.
- `{4}`: Match 4 instances of above group.

Comment: While this works on the simple example it will not work on the result I am looking for. Edited Question to refect what I want to achieve.

Comment: For edited problem, you can use: `(?:/germany/(?:[^-]*-){4}.*\d{3,}\.html|/product/view/id.*)$`  or see demo: https://regex101.com/r/gdITws/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?=(?:.*-){4,})
```

It starts from `start of string`, then uses a `look ahead`, looking for: any number of any character . This is repeated `4 or more times`.